# Android sqlite query to get tables with values greater than a value

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am using sqlite in my android app and it has (id, name, age) string tables.

I want the query to get names with age greater than 20.

I am using this query

```
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Favorite";
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_AGE = "age";

SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE age > 20
```

But i am getting wrong tables, there are few tables with age less than 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not clear to me. By the way, I think your query should be:

```
"SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " +  KEY_AGE + " > 20 ";
```

**Edit**

```
"SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE cast(age as INTEGER) > 20 ";
```

Comment: I am getting output, but the result is not correct. Thinking that the problem is age is stored as string and we can comparing it with integer value 20. Am i correct?

Comment: try with this "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE cast(KEY_AGE as INTEGER)  > 20 ";